# How to create an database file in the mongoose and return back in the json format

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, mongoose, mean-stack

Im reffering this video tutorial from this link "https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=node-js-express-rest-web-services&author=jonathan-mills&name=node-js-express-rest-web-services-m6&clip=2&mode=live"....Here im returning the student in the json format...But dont know how to create it...So im getting an empty one...Is there any way to create that in the mongoose...Any1 please check my code and say

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/studentAPI');

var studentinfo = require('./models/studentModel');

var app = express();

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var tutorRouter =express.Router();

    tutorRouter.route('/student')
    .get(function(req,res){

    studentinfo.find(function(err,student){
       if(err)
           res.status(500).send(err);
       else
           res.json(student);
     });

 });


 app.use('/api',tutorRouter)

 app.get('/',function(req,res){ 
 res.send('Welcome to my API')    
 });

 app.listen(PORT,function(){
  console.log('Running on port: ' + PORT); 
 });
```

**studentModel.js**

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
   Schema = mongoose.Schema();

 var studentModel = new mongoose.Schema({
   name:{
      type: String
    },
    parentname:{
       type: String
    }
   });

 module.exports = mongoose.model('studentinfo',studentModel);
```

Comment: 1. you are using `find` without any query params. 2. `find` returns an `array` of students and not one, you can use `findOne` for that. 3. where do you even try to create it? do you have something in the db at all? what do you mean you are getting it empty? in which stage do you want to create it? with what values do you want to create it?